# PHP Imagick load image with imagecreatefromjpeg instead of from file

Tags: php, imagick

This is the normal way:

```
$img = new Imagick('ttt.jpg');
$quality = $img->getImageCompressionQuality();
```

but what I want is:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('ttt.jpg');
$img = new Imagick($image);
$quality = $img->getImageCompressionQuality();
```

so I can make sure there will be no openbase issues when I copy the script to another server and forget to configure permissions for instance.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass GD image object to Imagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298075/pass-gd-image-object-to-imagick)

Comment: Nope @vixducis there Imagick only reads what gets drawn by PHP not created from file